# two NICs in one subnet and two dummy devices on same host -- routing

Tags: linux, networking, routing

For my tests I need to generate multiple flows with different source IP addresses, I thought that dummy devices would do the job.

I am using the following setup: on the same PC I have two NICs, connected back-to-back with a cable; I've configured policy routing so, that packets between these two interface are transferred over the cable, no loopback interface:

```
$ ip rule sh
1:      from 192.168.2.101 to 192.168.2.100 iif eth1 lookup local 
2:      from 192.168.2.100 to 192.168.2.101 iif eth2 lookup local 
3:      from 192.168.2.101 to 192.168.2.100 lookup main 
4:      from 192.168.2.100 to 192.168.2.101 lookup main
100:    from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
$
```

Now I've added two dummy devices (`ip link add xx type dummy`) dummy0 and dummy1 with IPs 10.10.10.1 and 20.20.20.1. What I'm trying to achieve now is that packets leaving off `dummy0` towards `dummy1` (e.g. `ping -I 10.10.10.1 20.20.20.1`) and the other way around, follow the route:

dummy0 <-> eth1 <-> eth2 <-> dummy1

What else in policy routing should I have to get it working? If it's easier to do with Linux network namespace, I'd be happy to have that solution as well! Thanks.

Comment: Dummy interfaces are usually used to assign a fixed IP address a long-running application can bind to, and then bridged to other interfaces as the infrastructure changes. So the natural way would be to bridge dummy0 with eth1 and dummy1 with eth2. But you didn't say *why* you think you need dummy interfaces.

Comment: @dirkt, for my tests I need to generate multiple flows with different source IP addresses, I thought that `dummy` devices would do the job.

Comment: You don't seem to have any rules at all for what happens to packets with source or destination IP addresses `10.10.10.1` and `20.20.20.1`. Those packets will just be routed by rule 100 which is `lookup local`, which will cause the packets to be received without ever hitting the wire. OTOH you have a bunch of rules for `192.168.2.x` which are not IP addresses that are used in your test at all. Are you sure you've documented your setup correctly? I feel like there's a missing piece of your setup that you haven't told us about.